# Alternative to Metashape software

Tags: software-recommendations, orthophoto, orthorectification

So I am from USA and our government decided to ban using any software products that is from Russia, can anyone from here suggest an alternative software with Agisoft Metashape?
Yeah I am upset about it but I have a lot of files that I have done from Metashape.
It is a lot to do with security issues they have an issues with.

What is the closest software to it ?

I have process many old 1930's black and white raw not-georeferenced aerial photos.

Comment: For software recommendations there is the [softwarerecs.se] Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you could ask your organisation to deploy Photoscan/Metashape inside a virtual machine? Alternatively, you could setup a dedicated network/VLAN to segregate the PC running Photoscan from the rest of the network. These types of solutions would allow you to continue using Photoscan without compromising network security etc.

Alternatively, [OpenDroneMap](https://www.opendronemap.org/) is an open source photogrammetry toolkit worth considering. It is free software, with a [paid option](https://opendronemap.org/webodm/download/#installer) if you need commercial support. You can install it on your own hardware, either 'bare metal' or within a VM or through Docker. Check out the documentation at https://www.opendronemap.org/docs/.

A popular approach is to install [WebODM](https://github.com/OpenDroneMap/WebODM) on a server within your organisation. This server is then accessed via a web browser, and from there you can process the imagery. The server can be made available to multiple users within your organisation, which might be useful if you are working in a team.

As far as I'm aware, the software is improving rapidly and is under active development. For example, NVIDIA GPU support is being introduced to speed up the tie-point matching and dense cloud processing etc. You will need to install it on a reasonably powerful computer; I'd suggest an 8 or 16 core CPU with 64GB or 128GB of RAM.